# react redux keep same order when update

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've got a list of users

and in case of follow action

I've this slice:

```
usersFollowSuccess: (state, action) => {
      const userId = action.payload._id;
      const filtered = state.data.filter((user) => {
        return user._id !== userId;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        data: [...filtered, action.payload],
        error: false,
        loaded: true,
      };
    },
```

All works fine but in the view the updated user

go at the last position.

How can I keep the same position in the view?
I've tried adding sort at the the end of map
with no luck.

### UPDATE

I've worked out with

```
const data = state.data.map((user) => {
        if (user._id === userId) {
          user = action.payload;
        }
        return user;
      });
```

Comment: I'd like to know the reason of the downvote ^^

Comment: Excuse me, Could I know what is same position mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

First of all, If you want to use `sort`. It is exactly before to `map` like

```js
items.sort(sortFunc).map(item=>(...));
```

You are mention **I've tried adding sort at the the end of map with no luck.** So, I guess you should sort item after render.

And, If you want to sort this Item at actions It is working

```js
usersFollowSuccess: (state, action) => {
      const userId = action.payload._id;
      const filtered = state.data.filter((user) => {
        return user._id !== userId;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        data: [...filtered, action.payload].sort(sortFunc),      // Here
        error: false,
        loaded: true,
      };
    },
```

#### ETC

Don't be annoying cuz of rude people :)